# Query Efficiency with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using an app that tracks the user location, and saves the route information to parse. As it stands I save the location, in a class, with a classname which is that of the location country, with the city as one of the keys. This means that in future when the app checks if someone has checked into a particular city, it queries parse for a class with the desired city as the class name, and I use a `query.whereKey("City", equalTo: queryCity)` constraint to see how many people used the app at that location. Would it be more or less efficient to just put all the locations into one class, with two keys (the country and city), and then query both of these when I need to retrieve that information?

essentially I'm asking which of these is a more efficient query, if there is even a difference.

```
var query = PFQuery(classname: queryCountry)
query.whereKey("City" equalTo: queryCity)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()
```

or

```
var query = PFQuery(classname: "Locations")
query.whereKey("Country", equalTo: queryCountry)
query.whereKey("City", equalTo: queryCity)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()
```

i.e. Is it better to let parse search through my classes, or search through the keys.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. Do you have a class in Parse for every country? What are you doing with this piece of code 

    'var query = PFQuery(classname: queryCountry)'

Comment: Yes, at the moment I have a class in parse for every country. I am using swift, so in that bit of code I am defining the query, as a PFQuery, with a class name that is the name of whatever country I am interested in. Basically, users track their own locations, and then they can also see who else checked in at their location, and it is this part that the query is referring to. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but in general, the limiting factor of an API is the data you send over the net. So you should think about sending requests to the API and demand only as much data as you really need.

Of course, two requests are more costly than only one request with larger data (due to the TCP overhead, connection establishment and so on). It is probably not significant most of the time. So you can do it either way.

However, if you need the data from queries anyway to proceed, I'd say you should combine it in one query.

*edit*

So you want to know how to organize your data. Well that is completely up to you. I don't think it makes a difference. However, using the second approach you don't have normalized data. I.e. in the unlikely but possible case that you want to rename a country, you have to do this in every row and this is very error-prone.

The first approach is not much better since one specific country is not a single class but rather an implementation of the class `Country`. So what you essentially want to do is:

- Class `Country` - with properties *name*, etc.
- Class `City` - with properties *name* etc. and a reference to the objectId in your `Country` table

Comment: Please see my edit to more specifically define my question, I have added code to the bottom to clarify

Comment: I edited my post. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

By taking the first approach, you're creating a new class in Parse for every Country, which will be a nightmare to maintain, especially when your country list is dynamic.

Performance, I don't think there would be a significant difference in query times in either approach. So this is a matter of personal preference.

Hope this helps.